# unexpected results from jQuery loop on dynamic HTML table

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a table that is created in `PHP`. This table is the result of a query and it generates several rows. Inside these rows are quite a few different elements, such as drop down menus (< select >s) check boxes, and text fields. I made a loop to go through the elements in `jQuery` and get the values, but it's not returning what I thought it would. This is a fairly complex situation, so I'm going to post the code and a fiddle to perfectly illustrate exactly what is happening, and what I expect to happen.

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['aid'])) {  
    $aid = $_POST['aid'];
    $projects = getProjects($db);
    $members = getUserName($db);            
    try {
        $project_info = $db->prepare("
            SELECT  projects.id,
                    projects.project_name,                  
                    projects.pm,    
                    projects.apm,
                    projects.est_start,
                    projects.est_end,
                    projects.contact,                   
                    projects.trips,
                    projects.tasks,
                    projects.perc_complete,
                    projects.bcwp,
                    projects.actuals,
                    projects.cpi,
                    projects.bcws,
                    projects.bac,
                    projects.comments,
                    projects.status,
                    projects.project_revenue,
                    projects.profit_margin,
                    projects.pm_perc,
                    projects.audited         
            FROM projects
            WHERE account_id = ?                        
        "); 

        $project_info->bindValue(1, $aid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $project_info->execute();       

            echo "<table class='projects_contentTable'>";
            echo "<thead class='projects_editable_thead'>";             
            echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "Job #" . "</th>";
            echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "Project Name" . "</th>";
            echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "PM" . "</th>";
            echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "APM" . "</th>"; 
            echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "Est. Start" . "</th>";
            echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "Est. End" . "</th>";
            echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "Contact" . "</th>";
            echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "Trips" . "</th>";
            echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "Tasks" . "</th>";
            echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "% Complete" . "</th>";
            echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "BCWP" . "</th>";
            echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "Actuals" . "</th>";
            echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "CPI" . "</th>";           
            echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "Comments" . "</th>";  
            echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "Status" . "</th>";    
            echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "Project Revenue" . "</th>";   
            echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "Profit Margin" . "</th>"; 
            echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "PM%" . "</th>";   
            echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "Audited" . "</th>";
            echo "</thead>";

            echo "<tbody class='projects_editable_tbody'>";                  
            while ($row = $project_info->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {             
                echo "<tr>";                            
                echo "<td class='projects_editable_content_td'>" . "<a href='#'>" . $row['id'] . "</a>" . "</td>";
                echo "<td class='projects_editable_content_td' contenteditable='true'>" . $row['project_name'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td class='projects_editable_content_td'>" . 
                        "<select id='table_edit_project_pm'>" . 
                            "<option value=''>" . $row['pm'] . "</option>" . 
                            "<option>" . "-----" . "</option>";
                        foreach($members as $key => $value) {
                            echo "<option value='".$key."'>" . $value . "</option>";            
                        } 
                echo "</select>";
                echo "</td>";               
                echo "<td class='projects_editable_content_td'>" . 
                        "<select id='table_edit_project_apm'>" . 
                            "<option value=''>" . $row['apm'] . "</option>" . 
                            "<option>" . "-----" . "</option>";
                        foreach($members as $key => $value) {
                            echo "<option value='".$key."'>" . $value . "</option>";            
                        } 
                echo "</select>";
                echo "</td>";               
                echo "<td class='projects_editable_content_td'>" . 
                    "<input type='text' id='table_edit_project_start' value='". $row['est_start'] ."'/>"; 
                echo "</td>";               
                echo "<td class='projects_editable_content_td'>" . 
                    "<input type='text' id='table_edit_project_end' value='". $row['est_end'] ."'/>";
                echo "</td>";               
                echo "<td class='projects_editable_content_td' contenteditable='true'>" . $row['contact'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td class='content_td'>" . $row['trips'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td class='content_td'>" . $row['tasks'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td class='content_td'>" . $row['perc_complete'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td class='content_td'>" . $row['bcwp'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td class='content_td'>" . $row['actuals'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td class='content_td'>" . $row['cpi'] . "</td>";             
                echo "<td class='projects_editable_content_td' contenteditable='true'>" . $row['comments'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td class='projects_editable_content_td'>" .
                        "<select>" .
                            "<option value=''>" . $row['status'] . "</option>" .
                            "<option>" . "-------" . "</option>" .
                            "<option>" . "On Hold" . "</option>" .
                            "<option>" . "In Progress" . "</option>" .
                            "<option>" . "Open" . "</option>" .
                            "<option>" . "Complete" . "</option>" .
                         "</select>"; 
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td class='content_td'>" . $row['project_revenue'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td class='content_td'>" . $row['profit_margin'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td class='content_td'>" . $row['pm_perc'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td class='projects_editable_content_td'>";                                   
                    if ($row['audited'] == 'true') {
                        echo "<input type='checkbox' checked='checked'/>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<input type='checkbox'/>";
                    }
                echo "</td>";               
                echo "</tr>";               
            }
            echo "</tbody>";    
            echo "</table>";                
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }   
} else {    
    echo 'could not load projects table';
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.projects_editable_tbody tr').each(function() {
        $('.projects_editable_content_td:not(:has(select)),option:selected').each(function() {
            saveEdits.push($(this).text());
        });
    }); 

    $.each(saveEdits, function(index, value) { 
        alert(index + ': ' + value); 
    });
```

OK end wall, so here is the fiddle to play with http://jsfiddle.net/U3nna/14/

Inside the fiddle I actually list the values I'm expecting and all you have to do is click the save button to see what is actually happening.

For those of you who don't want to use the fiddle, or perhaps can't here is your very brief summary.

I need to loop through the table and go through each table row. Inside each table row I need the text value from the < td >'s with the class " .projects_editable_content_td". Each of these values will be put into an array. *However* some of the values are not being stored, and also it seems that this loop does an extra iteration on the table. So sometimes I'm expecting 9 or 18 values, and I end up with 27 or 36, and the more I run it the worse it gets.

I'm wracking my brain but I can't seem to figure out why it wouldn't be picking up some of these elements text values. If anyone has the time to lend me a hand, i'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it so that you supply correct option values with each option (i.e. if you want Jane Doe to output Jane Doe then just use it for both the value and the content within the `option`).

You then need to add a third possibility for other `input`s, so I'd probably just rearrange the way you're going about this to:

```
$('td', this).each(function() {
    var $input = $("select, input", this);
    if($input.length) {
        saveEdits.push($input.val());
    }
    else saveEdits.push($(this).text());
});
```

Note that I changed the selector too. It looks like you're using classes a lot where you don't need them. If you **really** need to use classes so much, maybe try and make them a little nicer to read too (use `.projects-editable-content` e.g., use dashed not underscores, and don't make them longer than they need to be).

Comment: thank you very much, this is not only a good answer, it teaches good habits which i need because i'm just starting out

Comment: Still when I use this in my fiddle or in my code it won't work. Nothing happens when I click save. I have copied this exact code. Then I also tinkered with it changing "td" to ".projects_editable_content_td" and it still wont run. Is this meant to be more psuedo code than I'm expecting or is there a syntax error I'm not seeing?

Comment: Well then, this is working, but not *quite* as intended. Maybe this is where the confusion came in. I only want the values from the ".projects_editable_content_td" class < td > elements. Still rather nice work, and a very different way of doing it than I was using. I do like the cleanness of it

Comment: also, there are still null values in this array as the < select > elements are not being stored properly

Comment: Ok so just add the class back in :)

Comment: @i_me_mine - yes, that's why I said "change it so that you supply correct option values" :)

Comment: ok, so I *almost* have this working. take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WNSBk/3/). I just need this to store the actual option selected. Right now it's doing that, but it's **also** stores **all** the optional values

Comment: Yeh, remove the `option:selected` from your selector

Comment: I just removed `option:selected` from my `$('.projects_editable_content_td, option:selected', this).each` loop and now it **just** gives me all optional values, not the one selected. This process is just making me feel dumber by the minute. This should not be that hard to understand. The fact I'm so close and I keep trying variations of this loop and none of them work is making me so stressed.. :(

Comment: im just gonna ask another question. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

The problem is  you are getting only `$(this).text()` which misses the input (text/checkboxes) values 
Also one thing i notice that you have assigned the same id for morethan one elements , id is supposed to be unique for the html elements **table_edit_project_start** , **table_edit_project_end**

Try this

```
var saveEdits = [];
$('#save').click(function() {
    $('.projects_editable_tbody tr').each(function() { 
        $('.projects_editable_content_td:not(:has(select))>input')
            .each(function() {
              saveEdits.push($(this).val());
            });

        $('.projects_editable_tbody tr > .projects_editable_content_td:not(:has(select))')
            .each(function() {
              saveEdits.push($(this).text());
            });

    }); 
    $.each(saveEdits, function(index, value) { 
        alert(index + ': ' + value); 
    }); 
});
```

For duplicate value you can use the selector like `:eq(index),:gt(index)` so in the loop it will fetch the current tr's fields

```
var saveEdits = [];
$('#save').click(function() {
    $('.projects_editable_tbody tr').each(function(i) { 
        $('.projects_editable_tbody tr:eq('+i+') > .projects_editable_content_td:not(:has(select))>input')
            .each(function() {
              saveEdits.push($(this).val());
            });

      $('.projects_editable_tbody tr:eq('+i+') >.projects_editable_content_td:not(:has(select))')
            .each(function() {
              saveEdits.push($(this).text());
            });

   }); 
    $.each(saveEdits, function(index, value) { 
        alert(index + ': ' + value); 
    }); 
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/U3nna/26/)

Comment: awesome work, just looking at this makes more sense. I'm going to verify the work and probably mark this as solved. Thank you so much

Comment: hm, I went to your fiddle, and it's still returning some blank values, and it's also looping through the table more than once. As in there should be 17 values in the array. Yet there are many more. Something like 39. Any idea why?

Comment: Its just to make an idea now i will update the fiddle so it will get the values only once

Comment: well this is only getting the values once now, which is great. However there are still null values, like index 5 and 6 of the array. Also this starts at the 5th column of the table. The expected values listed below my table in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/U3nna/27/ are what I need. In this order, and no null values.

Comment: also, nice catch on the id's for start and end date. I did not realize that was still in here. This is why I was using so many classes, because you are right, id's can not have the same value. They must be unique

Comment: For ignoring null values you can do like this http://jsfiddle.net/U3nna/29/ but for order there will be some work to do the all values you want to get then place the input with hidden type containing the value correspond to the field and just loop through the .each for input only hope it makes sense i am done with my work thanks